# Javascript Calendar popup from ribbon button

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Does anyone have any examples of a calendar popup that can be triggered using a ribbon button on a form?

I'm looking to have a popup where the user can select a date from the calendar which will then pass the value back to the javascript that launched it. I've seen that this can be done from a html popup but my efforts to create this so far haven't really been successful, so was hoping someone could advise me on the best solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find a good calendar that I have used for this solution. It can be found at **https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday**

With this I put it into a html popup that had a text box on it (which would store the selected date) and had the javascript on my ribbon button show the popup.

The download includes the js files for the calendar to function and with a little tweaking of these you can make the calendar appear immediately on opening of the popup and not hide when a date is selected. Plus the text box can have its options changed so that it isn't visible to the user.

All put together this creates a rather pleasant looking calendar popup

Answer (score 0):

You can use the date parameter type from html without using javascript

```
<input type=date >
```